# Add new row to filtered DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am implementing filtering of dataGridView based on selected button.
If button 1 selected show only rows that have rID = 1, if 2 then only rID = 2 ...
That works fine.
Problem is with adding new rows in dataGridView. As soon as I add new row it is hidden from dataGridView because of filtering. I tried with:

```
private void dataGridView_UserAddedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = e.Row;
    row.Cells["rID"].Value = selectedRID;
}
```

but it is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

Use the RowValidating event instead of UserAddedRow.

```
private void dataGridView_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["rID"].Value = selectedRID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to use the RowValidated event. As per MSDN  [DataGridView.RowValidated Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowvalidated(v=vs.110).aspx)
you should "Use this event to perform post-processing on a row of values"

```
private void dataGridView_RowValidated(Objectsender,DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
{    
    dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["rID"].Value = selectedRID;
}
```